# batch write reg file fails with "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am trying to create reg file inside bat file with the following lines:

```
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 >tst222.reg
echo [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3297735606-1256148830-2878094939-1000\Software\GoldNET\Automate]>>tst222.reg
echo "ExecApplication4"="c:\\AttPlus\\go.bat,,"\Arj a -y <MivzaqBakDataPath>{MivIx}.arj <MivzaqMsgsDataPath>*.ms*"\,,"\<BankExplore> -I <MivzaqMsgsDataPath>*.msq -E"\">>tst222.reg
pause
```

The first line and the second go well but the third fails with the error:

> The system cannot find the file specified

what am I doing wrong in there and how can I solve this?

the exact line should appear like this in the reg file:

```
"ExecApplication4"="c:\\AttPlus\\go.bat,,\"Arj a -y <MivzaqBakDataPath>{MivIx}.arj <MivzaqMsgsDataPath>*.ms*\",,\"<BankExplore> -I <MivzaqMsgsDataPath>*.msq -E\""
```

P.S
i tried to do this threw reg add on the bat file and got similar error

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `^>` and `^<` instead, to 'escape' the `>` and `<` characters causing the problem (redirecting input/output). Line 3 :

```
echo "ExecApplication4"="c:\\AttPlus\\go.bat,,"\Arj a -y ^<MivzaqBakDataPath^>{MivIx}.arj ^<MivzaqMsgsDataPath^>*.ms*"\,,"\^<BankExplore^> -I ^<MivzaqMsgsDataPath^>*.msq -E"\">>tst222.reg
```

Example `echo` in cmd window, and output :

```
C:\>echo "ExecApplication4"="c:\\AttPlus\\go.bat,,"\Arj a -y ^<MivzaqBakDataPath
^>{MivIx}.arj ^<MivzaqMsgsDataPath^>*.ms*"\,,"\^<BankExplore^> -I ^<MivzaqMsgsDa
taPath^>*.msq -E"\"

"ExecApplication4"="c:\\AttPlus\\go.bat,,"\Arj a -y <MivzaqBakDataPath>{MivIx}.a
rj <MivzaqMsgsDataPath>*.ms*"\,,"\<BankExplore> -I <MivzaqMsgsDataPath>*.msq -E"
\"
```